# What is this "speaker" connector called?

Tags: pcb, connector

I am wondering what this connector is called and how I can identify if I can insert a bluetooth module for a wireless speaker. This is a display controller for a TV/monitor.

[image]

Comment: It really depends on what the circuit board is designed to do.  Why don’t you tell us about the board.

Comment: It might be reasonable to tell what the device is. Otherwise, no one can tell you what the speaker connector does. Maybe it is for connecting a speaker, or a pair of speakers, of unknown impedance and wattage.

Comment: @HandyHowie thanks. I edited the question. I am new at this so I am not sure how to ask good questions. It is a display controller.

Comment: @Justme Thanks, I just edited the question. It is a display controller.

Comment: The unspecified Bluetooth module will probably have a line level input, not a speaker level. Headphone outputs are generally suitable.

Comment: If you're looking for a part number, give us more information. Dimensions, including pin pitch? any markings on it? Similar-looking connectors that you know it's not? What's the mating connector look like?

Answer (score 1):

It is 4-pin [JST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector) header.
JST connectors have several variants. Most commonly used ones are:

- XH 2.50mm
- VH 3.96mm
- PH 2.00mm
- ZH 1.5mm
- GH 1.25mm

Your connector seems like XH variant.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the connector being a JST style connector, the output will be one of 4 possible types.

1. Amplified speaker output. Follow the traces and you'll likely find some beefy amplifier chips, and it connects directly to the raw speakers.
2. Pre-ampped line level output. Follow it and you'll find a mux or small amplifier chips. The final amplification is done by the speakers or on another board.
3. Non-amplified mic level output. No amplifier chips likely goes directly to a source IC. You will see amplifiers on the speakers.
4. Digital output. You'll see a DAC on the speakers.

Only 2 is really ideal for connecting to a Bluetooth board. With 3 you may be able to add your own pre-amp or get a Bluetooth module with a pre-amp.

4 will require a dac and 1 will be the most complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a board for a TV or monitor, it's a connector for the speakers. TVs generally have speakers for audio playback, and some monitors too.

Comment: Ok, but what is the connector called? Like the type of port?

Comment: I have no clue. Could be JST. But if you bought a board, doesn't the manual say what the connector type is and what it is for?

Comment: it is a connector with 4 pins labelled 'speaker'. we can only assume it connector to speakers of unknown specification. It could be anything - you need to get a schematic for the the unit in question or reverse engineer the circuit. There is no standard specification - each manufacturer can do what they like. Can you connect a bluetooth module? It might work or it might not. Without specific knowlege, it is a guess.